# Why user is not authenticated after google authorization in nuxt-auth-next?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I am using the following config for nuxt-auth-next in my nuxt application

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
auth: {
  strategies:{
    google: {
    clientId: "my_client_id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    redirectUri: `http://localhost:3000/apps`,
    codeChallengeMethod: '',
    scope: ['profile', 'email'],
    responseType: 'token id_token'
    }
  },
  redirect: {
    login: '/login',
    logout: false,
    home: '/apps',
    callback: false
  }
},

router: {
  middleware: ['auth']
}
```

And this is my `login.vue` file

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <template>
        <b-button @click="loginClicked()">Login with Google</b-button>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    async loginClicked() {
      try {
        await this.$auth.loginWith('google');
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("login error: " + err);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I press **Login with Google** button from my login page, it goes to Google authentication page, successfully passes authentication, goes to localhost:3000/apps page(my redirect url) and then immediately returns to localhost:3000/login - and this.$auth.loggedIn is false.

I've already visited https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/1127, but that did not help. Am I missing something?

```json
"@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1624817847.21691f1",
"nuxt": "^2.15.8"
```

*Vue devtools after I press 'Login with Google'*
[image: Vue devtools after I press 'Login with Google']

Comment: Hi, what do you see in your Vue devtools with the logged-in state of the module?

Comment: if I manually edit loggedIn to "true" value in devtools, application page "apps" loads fine

Comment: If I change lib from nuxt/auth-next to nuxt/auth, authorization works fine

Comment: It all depends if you need the latest v5 features or if v4 is good enough.

Comment: seems that v4 features are ok for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on [this page](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/status/), `auth-next` aka v5 is still in beta and you may encounter some bugs, even tho it is more rich in terms of features.

If you are fine with what the Nuxt module provides with the v4, sticking to it may be a more stable solution.